# Login to GMail using yourname@domain.com

Tags: gmail, google-account

I've set up a domain and linked the email there with Google using Settings > Account for sending emails (and I ticked treat as alias). As well as connecting by POP3 to get the emails.

However I want to be able to login to this GMail account using yourname@domain.com email address. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you referring to "Gmail for business"? If not then I don't believe you can login using another "alias" (or "send mail as" option). You need to login using your primary google account email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's Google's support topic regarding additional login email addresses:

> To add an alternate email address to your Google Account, just follow
>   these steps:
>
> - Sign in to your account on the Google Accounts homepage.
> - Click Edit next to 'Email addresses.'
> - Add your alternate email address in the 'Add an additional email address' field.
> - Click Save.

Source: http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=86635